Starting a manual car in first gear. Is it harmful?
Starting the car in 1st gear (instead of in neutral and THEN shifting into first): Does this cause extra wear on the engine or transmission components?
Or perfectly safe?
Guy I know is doing this a lot, out of habit.

Do you mean the gear in first, with the clutch pedal pushed all the way down?

@GdD - I'm pretty sure that's what they mean. I'm pretty sure we've had this question asked before, too. Just can't find it in my limited amount of time.

Yes , that's what I mean. Is it harmful to do repeatedly?

There's nothing mechanically wrong with starting the car in gear in a manual car, as long as the clutch is fully disengaged. With the clutch disengaged there's no transfer of energy from the engine to the transmission, so no wear considerations. You can do that as many times as you like without issues.
It's not good practice because if the clutch isn't fully disengaged your car could jolt forward or backward depending on the gear it was left in, which is a safety concern, and it can damage your starter motor. If your foot slips off the clutch after start your car might begin to roll, which again is a safety issue. So it's best to start it in neutral.

There is one wear concern of starting the car with the clutch pedal pushed down, that being the throwout bearing. However, at least here in the States, all manual vehicles have a "neutral safety switch" which is activated (deactivated?) when you depress the pedal, which makes the wear on the throwout bearing moot anyway (no getting around it). I understand other places in the world beyond the States do not have a NSS associated with the clutch, so your mileage may vary.

All the manual cars I've driven in the UK and Europe have a neutral safety switch, they won't let you start with the clutch out.
